# How to keep history of search input after opening search result then go back by the browser button as google search in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

If I have search input and I typed a keyword to search for it, then press enter, the search results are appeared.

Clicking on any search result would navigate me to its result info, how can I retrieve the searched keyword if I used the back button in the
browser?

Comment: Try to implement "autocomplete". Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you insert data on a page, leave the page and then want to come back to it and find the inserted data there. If this is the case, you could look into a store: 
These two are examples of stores:
https://mobx.js.org/best/store.html

https://github.com/angular-redux/store